# Angular 2 CanActivate does not work in prameterised router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router

I have created a route guard,  read a few blogs and Angular 2 official documentation on it. It works in non-parameter routes, but it will not work in parameterized routes.

Code sample,

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'Customers', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'CustomerProfile/:id', component: DriverProfileComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'Customers', pathMatch: 'full' },
        ]
    }
];
```

auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _localStorage: LocalStorageService,
    ) { }

    menus: any = {
        dashboard: [
            '/dashboard/Customers',
            '/dashboard/CustomerProfile'
        ],
        driver: [],
        client: [
            '/client/account-setup'
        ]
    };

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        let url: string = state.url;
        let menus: string[] = this.menus[this._localStorage.get('type') + ''];
        console.log(state.url); /* /dashboard/ClientProfile/1 */

        if (menus.indexOf(url) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "will not work" mean? Does it always grant access? Does it always deny access? Does it effect an error?

Comment: @cartant when I am logging state.url, the URL have the parameter. my actual URL is /dashboard/CustomerProfile But am getting this /dashboard/CustomerProfile/1

Comment: In Child routing also import CanActivate

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are getting /dashboard/CustomerProfile/1? That looks correct, matching your second child route?